# ColdFusion application timing out even with large values for cflogin idletimeout and session timeout

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, session-timeout

Sessions on my ColdFusion server appear to be timing out every 20 minutes for one of my apps, even though I have high (on the order of many hours) timeouts set for both `idletimeout` and `this.SessionTimeout` in the CFC.

These timeouts occur regardless of whether I visit the pages during that 20 minute period — in other words, the sessions are not even idle for 20 minutes, it's just that 20 minutes after login, the user becomes unauthenticated again — the value of `#IsUserLoggedIn()#` becomes NO and the value for `#GetAuthUser()#` becomes blank.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into this before and if there are any fixes.

Also, it's not clear in the documentation how ColdFusion determines that the user and login session are idle. It would be great to know where this session data is stored and, ideally, to peek at it and see what might be causing this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Do other applications on the same server have longer timeouts that are working?

If you do not, then it probably that you can set a maximum sessionTimeout in Cold Fusion Administrator. This is likely the cause.

[Configuring and using session variables (CF9)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html#WS7BC953A6-8CA7-4759-BDDF-15000CBCC0CD)

> Specify a maximum session time-out. Application code cannot set a time-out greater than this value. The default value for this time-out is two days.

Also, can you edit your question to provide some code? Show us your your application configuration.

Also, is there a chance you have an application with the same name and different timeout configuration that is causing a conflict. Honestly this is just a ballpark guess because I'm very careful with application names.

Comment: Thanks, I did already set the max session timeout. It doesn't appear that other apps are having this problem. I'll try to add some source code. Unfortunately I am going to have to edit it somewhat…